# Java Programming ---> Future [ inputs . length ]

Tags: java, warnings, future

This is a small part of my code. I am getting a warning in the 4th line, which is this line :

```
Future<String>[] results = new Future[inputs.length]; // Stores the results
```

The warning is basically in the `[inputs.length]` part due to which I cannot execute the for loops. 
The warning is :

> Multiple markers at this line - Type safety: The expression of type `Future[]` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Future<String>[]` - Type safety: The expression of type `Future[]` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Future<String>[]`

Could you please suggest a way I would not have to change the for loops but could remove the warning from the 4th line?

```
public StringBuilder fieldAggregator(String... inputs)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      Future<String>[] results = new Future[inputs.length]; // Stores the results
      for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { // Submits the tasks to thread pool
        results[i] = pool.submit(new ValidateInput<String>(inputs[i], pool));
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { // Aggregates the results
        sb.append(results[i].get());
      }
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact warning message?

Comment: Yep don't paraphrase, but show the message itself. Also, is all of your code fully left-justified? If so, how do you read it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You could use a chalkboard to count the braces.

Comment: The warning is : Multiple markers at this line - Type safety: The expression of type Future[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Future<String>[] - Type safety: The expression of type Future[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Future<String>[]

Comment: @millimoose: I suppose I should have been more blunt. If he's asking others for free advice, it isn't asking too much of him to clean up his code a little for our benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays with a generic type parameter do not exist. Use a collection instead.

Comment: An ArrayList<Future<String>> would be a good replacement I guess.

Comment: Yes, for best performance initialized with a capacity of `inputs.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects that should know **precise** type of stored data to ensure type safety in runtime. With generics type stored in `<SomeType>` is erased in runtime, so JVM can't check if you actually trying to put `Future` element that stores `<SomeType>` or maybe `<SomeOtherType>` so it is threated as dangerous behavior and that is why you have warning.

If you are absolutely sure that data in array will be correct try to suppress that warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Future<String>[] results = new Future[inputs.length];
```

but I would advise using some collection like `ArrayList<Future<String>>` rather then arrays with generics.

Comment: No need to go that way if you can just replace it with a collection.